# Fatal error: Non-abstract method NF_Handlers_FieldsetRepeater::isFieldsetData() must contain body in

Tags: html, wordpress, ninja-forms

Would really like some help! I tried removing the semicolon but still getting this error:

> Fatal error: Non-abstract method NF_Handlers_FieldsetRepeater::isFieldsetData() must contain body in /home/warstdam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Handlers/FieldsetRepeater.php on line 173

```
/**
 * Determine if data matches fieldset repeater construct
 *
 * When given only a submission value without any meta data, check the
 * construct of the value to asssert with some level of confidence that
 * the value is from a fieldset repeater.
 *
 * Logic: 
 *  - is submission empty? then NO, we don't assert is fieldset repeater data
 *  - can the array key be parsed as a fieldset repeater key?  If not, then NO…
 *  - is each value an array with 'id' and 'value' keys,
 *    and the `id` matches the id of its parent?  If not, then NO...
 *
 * If all the above conditions are met for every entry in the submission,
 * we assert that the submission value is that of a fieldset repeater.
 * 
 *  
 * @param array $submission
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isFieldsetData(array $submission); bool
{
    $return = true;

    // If not array containing data, not fieldset repeater
    if (empty($submission)) {
        $return = false;
    }

    foreach($submission as $key=>$submissionValueArray){
        $submissionReference = $this->parseFieldsetFieldReference($key);

        if(-1===$submissionReference){
            $return = false;
        }

        if(!isset($submissionValueArray['id'])
           || $key!==$submissionValueArray['id']
           || !isset($submissionValueArray['value'])){
            $return = false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the end of the code

```
{
    $return = [];

    if (!is_array($fieldSubmissionValue)) {
        return $return;
    }

    if(''!==$fieldId and []!== $fieldSettings){

        $fieldsetLabelLookup = $this->getFieldsetLabels($fieldId, $fieldSettings);
        $fieldsetTypeLookup = $this->getFieldsetTypes($fieldId,$fieldSettings);
    }else{
        
        $fieldsetLabelLookup = null;
        $fieldsetTypeLookup = null;
    }


    // $completeFieldsetID is in format {fieldsetRepeaterFieldId}{fieldsetDelimiter}{fieldsetFieldId}{submissionIndexDelimiter}{submissionIndex}
    foreach ($fieldSubmissionValue as $completeFieldsetId => $incomingValueArray) {

        // value is expected to be keyed inside incoming value array
        if (isset($incomingValueArray['value'])) {
            $value = $incomingValueArray['value'];
        } else {
            $value = $incomingValueArray;
        }

        // attempt parsing of fielsetField; if any fail, exit as data is corrupt
        $fieldsetWithSubmissionIndex = $this->parseFieldsetFieldReference($completeFieldsetId);

        if (0 == $fieldsetWithSubmissionIndex['fieldsetFieldId']) {

            return $return;
        }

        $parsedSubmissionIds = $this->parseSubmissionIndex($fieldsetWithSubmissionIndex['fieldsetFieldId']);

        if (-1 === $parsedSubmissionIds['submissionIndex']) {
            return $return;
        }

        $fieldsetFieldId = $parsedSubmissionIds['fieldsetFieldId'];


        $submissionIndex = $parsedSubmissionIds['submissionIndex'];

        $idKey = $fieldId . $this->fieldsetDelimiter . $fieldsetFieldId;

        if(is_null($fieldsetTypeLookup)){
            $fieldsetFieldType='';
        }else{
            $fieldsetFieldType = $fieldsetTypeLookup[$idKey];
        }
        
        if(is_null($fieldsetLabelLookup)){
            $fieldsetFieldLabel='';
        }else{
            $fieldsetFieldLabel = $fieldsetLabelLookup[$idKey];
        }


        $array = [];
        $array['value'] = $value;
        $array['type'] = $fieldsetFieldType;
        $array['label'] = $fieldsetFieldLabel;

        $return[$submissionIndex][$fieldsetFieldId] = $array;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

}

Comment: Is it this section i need to add something else? public function isFieldsetData(array $submission); bool
{
    $return = true;

Comment: (The code block introduced as *the end of the code* is broken: look at the orphaned `}` below it.) I find it least error prone to enclose code in lines containing just `~~~`. `$return` is boolean in the first block, subscribed in the second: a state I find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error.
Change `; bool` to `: bool`.

```php
public function isFieldsetData(array $submission): bool
```

Comment: When I do that it says this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/warstdam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Handlers/FieldsetRepeater.php on line 207

Comment: @Lou. Okay, what's in line 207 ? Could you update the question showing that part too ?

Comment: No It is sayihng: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/warstdam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Handlers/FieldsetRepeater.php on line 454

Comment: I managed to fix the syntax on line 173 but now it says it doesn't have an end of file? Sorry I'm so new to this and just trying to help a friend with her website.

Comment: @Lou. Okay, what's in line 454 ? Could you update the question showing that part too ?

Comment: @Lou By the way, I updated the answer. Try this version now.

Comment: }

        return $return;
    }
}

Comment: @Lou Undo all the changes, go back to the beginning of the code where it was `; bool`. Change that to `: bool`.

Comment: With that new change it goes back to: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/warstdam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Handlers/FieldsetRepeater.php on line 173

Comment: I've also tried delteing the whole plug in of ninja forms and re installing and it has the same error.

Comment: @Lou . You could try to replacing only that single file. Download the latest version here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/

Comment: So i installed it and get the same error. How do I replace the single file? Thank you so much for your help so far!!

Comment: @Lou No problem man. If installing the whole plugin doesn't change, then I guess it wont matter much. But to replace a single file, you can just download and open the zip, then copy paste the content of that file.

Comment: Ah that doesn't help either - I've raised it with Ninja i wonder if anyone else is having this issue!

Comment: @Lou . You can also try posting in the [forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ninja-forms/). Moreover, update the question and the code with the new source. Someone else might know the answer !